# one client multi IPSEC server with same configuration

Tags: ipsec, openswan

I am able to establish IPSEC connection between one client per server. Actually I can connect multi Ipsec server at the same time. But I have realized that when servers have same xl2tpd.conf file like following

```
    [global]
 ipsec saref = yes
 listen-addr = 12.34.56.78

 [lns default]
 ip range = 192.168.1.10-192.168.1.20
 local ip = 192.168.1.1
 ;require chap = yes
 refuse chap = yes
 refuse pap = yes
 require authentication = yes
 ppp debug = yes
 pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
 length bit = yes
```

Server 1 can be reachable via 192.168.1.1 ip address however
Server 2 can be reachable via different one assigned randomly say 162.xx.xx.xx though in xl2tpd.conf->local ip is set 192.168.1.1.
Actually I am not expecting to reach diffent machines with same ip address.
But how can I make server unique by modifiying the  xl2tpd.conf files of all servers.

Answer (score 0):

settting "local ip" per server with different ip address solves the issue.

;server 1 ; local ip = 192.168.1.1
;server 2 ; local ip = 192.168.1.2
;server 3 ;local ip = 192.168.1.3

Be sure that ip range = 192.168.1.10-192.168.1.20 does not cover servers' "local ip".